# FHIR: Slicing extensions

Tags: hl7-fhir

Slicing of DataElements is defined once per path (only one set of discriminators per unique path).  This works for built-in elements, but extension is (and must be) sliced only by url.  As a result, it appears that further (more detailed) slicing of an extension isn't possible.

For example, consider an extension to Patient for research authorizations, ext url "http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth".

It has an extension sub-element "authorizationType" (http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth.type) of type Code.  Here are two instances of this extension (one type "local", one "national").

```
<extension url="http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth">
  <extension url="http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth.type">
    <valueCode value="local" />
  </extension>
  <extension url="http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth.flag>
    <valueBoolean value="true" />
  </extension>
</extension>
<extension url="http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth">
  <extension url="http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth.type">
    <valueCode value="national" />
  </extension>
  <extension url="http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth.flag>
    <valueBoolean value="false" />
  </extension>
</extension>
```

The StructureDefinition for this would include (from Patient):

```
...snip...
<element>
  <path value="Patient.extension" />
  <slicing>
    <discriminator value="url" />
  </slicing>
</element>
```

I could add an element for researchAuthorization by using type.Profile to define the extension URL, but can I add a slicing as shown?

```
<element>
  <path value="Patient.extension" />
  <slicing>
    <discriminator value="url" />
  </slicing>
</element>
<element>
  <path value="Patient.extension" />
  <name value="researchAuthorization" />
  <slicing>
    <discriminator value="url" />
    <discriminator value="extension["http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth.type"].code" />
  </slicing>
  <type>
    <profile value="http://example.com/DataElement/researchAuth" />
  </type>
</element>
```

The second  is now legal since it "satisfies" the first slicing via type.profile.@value being fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for a set of sliced data to have multiple discriminators.  Whether the existing tooling will support this for extensions is a different question.  You may need to manually author your profile.

Comment: Yes, a sliced element may have multiple discriminators.  BUT, any one slice can only have one *set* of discriminators (one <slicing> definition).  For the extension element, that <slicing> definition *always* defines url as the sole discriminator.  So, for a particular extension, there is no way to discriminate more granularly.  Yes?

Comment: If you're generating the profile from a spreadsheet, that's true.  However, if you create the Profile XML directly, you can have as many discriminators as you wish.

Comment: I've expanded the example...I understand that multiple discriminators are allowed.  What I'm unclear on is how this applies to extensions since their discriminator is already set in the base (standard) profile.

Comment: What wording in the spec leads you to believe that you can't add an additional slicing?  Slicing slices is intended to be legal.

Comment: I inferred it (perhaps wrongly!) from http://hl7-fhir.github.io/profiling.html#2.14.0.8 and especially _The structure definition SHALL ensure that there is no overlap between the set of values and/or codes in the value sets between slices._  A set of discriminators _appear_ to act as a "primary key" for a particular path. If there can be multiple conflicting sets of discriminators per path, how would an implementer determine which to use?  More concretely, how would we match a particular element from a resource instance to a particular StructureDefinition element?

Comment: Or, is my example legal since I can determine that I'm on a particular slice since I've "fixed" the URL by <type><profile> and now I can add another <slicing>?  In other words, once you've satisfied the resolution of the first slicing by fixing the discriminator you are free to add additional slices?

Comment: More time working through this...do the discriminators of the "sub-slicing" need to be a super-set of the "base" slicing?  E.g. do I have to include "url" in all extension sub-slicings?  If not, how do I determine order of precedence in slicing definitions (in the example, which element/slicing do I resolve first)?  Element order in the resource?

Comment: Well, in theory in the differential part of a StructureDefinition you could just slice by something new.  But that would make life pretty miserable for the software trying to generate the snapshot view.  So in practice, the discriminators of the slices in a child profile need to include the discriminators from the parent profile.  There is no order of precedence.  Every "sub slice" should include a fixed value for all discriminators.